# IOS Swift Open View Controller Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, appdelegate

can you help me what is the best/proper way to launch ViewControllers programmatically?

For example,

- I have a `LoginViewController`, a `ListViewController`, and an `ItemViewController`.
- `LoginViewController` is launched first then it verifies the token/account through an API asynchronously.
- After it is verified, it will go to `ListViewController`.

What I want to do is, for example the app is opened through `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey` or `launchedwithRemoteNotification`, I would open `ItemViewController` programatically.

I can do this by showing a `viewcontroller` in

```
let currentView = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
```

then present the view from it. However, i think `presentedViewController` is `nil` when the app is opened on the first time. I can make some work arounds, but is there a more proper or standard way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboard

Comment: @jaxx05, Is any controller is presented over self.window?.rootViewController ?

Comment: @Rohi rootViewController is the LoginViewController

Comment: Is this duplicate? I think my scenario is entirely different from the linked question

Comment: @ jaxx05, then on app launch check for respective rootviewcontroller and present ItemViewController over that instead of presenting over self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @Rohi. In this case, the ItemViewController Will be presented on LoginViewController, which will soon be replaced since after by the ListViewController.  I guess I really have to wait until the ListViewController is presented, and present it from there

Comment: @ jaxx05 , Are you presenting ItemViewController over ListViewController which is presented on LoginViewController?

Answer (score 2):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil)
let articleController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ArticleViewController")
```

And this is how you can set the identifier of your view controller :

[image]

Comment: Does this create a new instance of the storyboard?

Comment: Yes it does. You can then present articleController using presentViewController or push it to a navigation controller.

Comment: @Nitish what if i dont have any view controler in storyboard but all is  i am doing programatically then what should i do to call or declare view controller's id